# Why does it take so long to join a wifi network?

Tags: wireless, wifi, latency

Accessing a text-only website, including TLS handshake, averages under half a second from first `GET` request to completely loaded, using my none-too-fast wifi. Yet connecting to a wifi network that I connect to daily, setting aside new networks for the moment, averages upwards of twenty seconds. While I can think of plenty of explanations for a few round trips taking this long, I can't seem to think of any justification that would make connecting slow but communicating over an existing connection fast, unless it's something specific to the wifi protocol.

Here are the reasons I've thought through, and why they're most probably wrong:

- Lost packets forcing retries *ad nauseaum* - Would result in slow communication after connection
- Heavy compute involved in the handshake - The TLS handshake is almost instantaneous for comparison
- Bottlenecked resources on the router specific to initiating connections - Not ridiculous, but what resources?
- Clever balancing of load only happens after connection is complete - This is my best idea so far I think, that the coordination of all the cleverness that makes wifi fast requires an existing connection to communicate over, but I don't know what those optimizations are exactly

**Edit:**

A few folks in the comments asked for additional details, as connecting to wifi isn't slow on every device, so I'll clarify that the slow connection times asked about are reproducible on most every network I've tried, on multiple iPhone models from 2017 to 2020, and multiple MacBook Pro models from 2015 to 2021. Let's specifically disregard IoT devices, as I've seen those connect far faster, which if anything is the plot thickening

Comment: This question may be off-topic here (I'm not sure), and you could improve it greatly by giving more details of your network setup and devices. But it certainly doesn't _inherently_ take 20+ seconds. I have IoT devices with very low power and compute capability which can activate their radios and join a preselected AP in about 1 second.

Comment: How can the time it takes to load a text-only website be compared to setting up a WiFi connection? They're completely unrelated things. So an apples to pears comparison. My devices only need a couple of seconds to connect to my WiFi network, not 20 seconds on average. So that's something with your network and not WiFi in general.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the purpose of the comparison was to identify that most logical explanations for connection times being slow, like lots of dropped packets, would also make using an existing connection slow, eliminating most explanations

Comment: @TypeIA Good point! I edited the question to clarify it to specific devices

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few possible authentication and crypto schemes for wifi, and consumer gear (especially Apple consumer gear) REALLY likes to present a simple user interface.

Rather then asking the user to select an authentication and crypto scheme, they would far rather grab the password and then just try each possibility in tern until they find one that works....

Smart access point designers deliberately do not make authentication attempts that fail return the 'you failed' message quickly, having the whole cycle take a few seconds per attempt discourages dictionary attacks.

Then of course a lot of that stuff once it gets a wifi connection to the local network likes to see if it has an internet connection (as opposed to just a local LAN) which means it needs to do the DHCP dance to get an IP address and then try phoning home to see if anyone answers. More time is burned there.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense